# How do I limit a certain process' CPU consumption on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have an app consisting of multiple services. Sometimes one of the services starts to consume the entire CPU and doesn't allow other services (mostly user facing) to work properly. As a result the user experience is bad. Is there a way to limit those services CPU consumption or give priority to the user-facing ones so the user experience always gets the highest priority?

Comment: You need to look into affinity masks.